# How to replace all negative values in vector by 0 in R

Tags: r, vector

I have a randomly generated vector from a normal distribution with 50 elements

```
vector<-c(rnorm(50))
```

I want to change all negative values to 0 and positive values to 1

I used this function and indexing however then I do not get vector with 50 elements

```
vector[ vector< 0 ] <- 1
vector[ vector> 0 ] <- 0
```

How should I proceed?

Comment: Why not simply `sample(0:1,50,replace=T)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generate some data

```
x = rnorm(50)
```

then either

```
x = ifelse(x > 0, 1, 0)
```

or

```
x[x < 0] = 0 
x[x > 0] = 1
```

Or even better

```
  as.numeric (x>0)
```

However since the standard normal is symmetric about 0, why not simulate directly via

```
sample(0:1, 50, replace=TRUE)
```

Comment: `as.numeric(x > 0)` should be the simplest one IMO

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in the first query you replace all value smaller 0 by values larger zero 
so the trick is to switch

```
vector[ vector< 0 ] <- 1
vector[ vector> 0 ] <- 0
```

into

```
vector[ vector> 0 ] <- 0
vector[ vector< 0 ] <- 1
```

Note that you are also slightly biased towards 0 but that should only be marginal